# Laravel “davibennun/laravel-push-notification”

Tags: android, push-notification, laravel-5

I am using `davibennun/laravel-push-notification` in laravel framework for push notification, it worked well in iphone device but in android it gives

> "Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection gcm-http.googleapis.com"

I also tried with

```
$push = PushNotification::app('Androidpush');
$push->adapter->setAdapterParameters(['sslverifypeer' => false]);
$push->to($deviceToken)->send('Hello World, i`m a push message');
```

Comment: Also share your Device token format, so We can know that you are passing correct token format

Comment: Thanks for response
`$deviceToken = "dxu8XvChIXg:APA91bEUASmBE_bpDzHlgvf9RZhLYE4W7ni5xeRZ-ze-QKE-1uUFbTcWkGJ05GkbTWbcU8tceA_rnUwDgBr8w46cylkkvz9ORoCmdqSt8AoVviGRdQbcM1GtbDZqWdcSpyJpZPSX2SRP";` @Qazi